# ¿como puedo recargar mi tabla con ajax sin necesidad de recargar toda la pagina?

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax

Quisiera actualizar mi `datatable` y no tener que refrescar toda la pagina.

Tengo este formulario con la tabla:

```
<div class="row filaSuperior">
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form action="" id="formulario_productos" method="post" class="text-center" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Nombre Producto:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input required type="text" class="form-control nombre_producto" style="color: #fff;" autocomplete="off" name="nombre_producto" placeholder="Nombre Producto">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Reseña Producto:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input required type="text" class="form-control descripcion_producto" style="color: #fff;" autocomplete="off" name="descripcion_producto" placeholder="Descripcion Producto">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-block guardarProductos" onclick="name()" name="guardadoProductos" value="GUARDAR">
        </div>

    </form>
    <div id="respuesta">
    </div>
</div>
</div><br>
<div class="col-sm-3 cal"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 text-center" id="tablaProductos">
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive dataTable" id="table_id">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre Producto</th>
            <th>Descripcion Producto</th>
            <th>Nombre Tipo Producto</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            {foreach item=Producto from=$arrayProductos}
            <tr> 
            <th>{$Producto.nombre_producto}</th>
            <th>{$Producto.descripcion_producto}</th>
            <th>{$Producto.nombre_tipo_producto}</th>              
            <td>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info editarProducto" name="editarProducto" id="">                            
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_producto" class="id_producto"value="{$Producto.id_producto}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">                        
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger eliminarProducto" name="eliminar" >                           
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" name="borrarProducto"></span>
                    </button>
                    <input type="hidden" class="id_producto"  value="{$Producto.id_producto}">
                </div>
            </div>                 
            </td>

            </tr>
            {/foreach}
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Y este es mi `jquery` con el `ajax`:

```
$('#formulario_productos').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var nombre_producto = $('.nombre_producto').val();
    var descripcion_producto = $('.descripcion_producto').val();
    var tipo_producto = $('.tipo_producto').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "save.php",
        data: { nombre_producto, descripcion_producto, tipo_producto, funcion: 'guardarProducto' },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("todo esta correcto");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("erro" + data);
        }
    })


});
```

No he podido actualizar solo la tabla por lo que he estado usando `location.reload()` que me refresca toda la pagina. Este es un formulario en el que almaceno productos con sus detalles y demás, ya el formulario envía correctamente los datos a la `db` pero el tema de la recarga si lo veo como difícil xD.

También intenté moverme entre padres e hijos en el `query` de esta forma, pero no lo logré.

```
$(this).parent('div').siblings('.data').reload();
```

Agradezco de corazón cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Una forma de hacerlo es consultar con ajax y que te devuelva los datos que vas a colocar en la tabla en formato json, y lo insertas en la tabla, es algo extenso pero es una forma de hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Podrías poner todo el tbody en un helper, e inyectarlo con sus datos cada vez que lo requieras, si es que quieres refrescar toda la información desde bd con ajax. 
O como te comentan, agregar o eliminar sólo un elemento trow según la operación que hagas, en el tbody.

Comment: Hola, las respuestas sin código son consideradas de baja calidad. Revisa [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que conozcas como escribir buenas respuestas.